# Entity Framework System.InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am new to Entity Framework. I am trying a simple operation that I am setting an object property with a selected object from another DbSet:

```
review.Book = (Book)db.Books.Skip(rnd.Next(db.Books.Count())).Take(1);
```

It is throwing an "Invalid Cast Exception". I am just setting the Book property of "review" object with a "Book" returned from a DB query. What is wrong on this?

The error message is:
System.InvalidCastException
HResult=0x80004002
Message=Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[EFCoreIA.Entities.Book]' to type 'EFCoreIA.Entities.Book'.

Answer (score 1):

Take returns a list of objects see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=net-6.0

you probably want

```
review.Book = (Book)db.Books.Skip(rnd.Next(db.Books.Count())).First;
```

Comment: Yes, I had not noticed that. Using .First or .Single() resolved the issue. Thanks!